# Grabbing images from a page for Pinterest pinit button

Tags: javascript, pinterest

I am using Pinterest share button for my website. The expected behavior i want is whenever i press pin it button it shall show me all iamges on the page and give me an option to pin one from them.

Just like pin it button on http://www.dogster.com/the-scoop/minkyu-lee-adam-and-dog-nominated-for-an-oscar

However, pin it api present at http://pinterest.com/about/goodies/ needs a hardcode media url for pinning.

I am not sure how to grab this behavior from Pinterest, can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/t4KHR/1/ ?

Comment: you are hard coding image url's

Comment: i wouldn't call it hard coding, i am using `encodeURIComponent()` to prevent sending unexpected requests to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

http://business.pinterest.com/widget-builder/#do_pin_it_button

It does give me the desired behavior. It was totally hidden from dev stuff at Pinterest

Comment: I wouldn't call a subdomain that is in Google totally hidden. Also you should look into Structured Metadata and Rich Pins.